# Is it possible to have a content review process for Stack Overflow for Teams questions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Is it possible to have alerts, or a way of searching for questions in Stack Overflow for Teams that haven't been added to / reviewed for a period of time?

i.e We want to make sure that answers don't get out of date, and would like to have a six monthly review process for each where an appropriate body reviews the answer and updates or signs off as appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find a way to detect unmodified answers using the following search terms which will work for us, as we can edit the answer once reviewed with a review date:

```
lastactive:2018-01-01..2018-07-01 is:answer
```

Comment: You could use `is:a lastactive:..6m` instead